# How to keep texture mapping after applying modifiers

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I've created a street by adding a street texture on a plane. I created a curve and added an array modifier and curve modifier on the plane. I made it let the plane follow the curve.

It looks like this:

[image: Street, texture preview and modifier settings]

I need to export this now. For this (I guess) I need to apply the modifiers. Unfortunately the texture mapping is changing.

Is there a way to keep the texture mapping but after applying the modifiers?

Edit:
Here the versions with applied modifiers:

[image]

It seems that applying the array modifier removes the texture repeat and applying the curve modifier removes the texture... distortion.

And here my [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35929).

Comment: I assume it is the Curve modifier that is the issue, not the array (try applying the array without a fit type and use the curve modifier to curve it).

Comment: What does it look like with the mapping broken

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Added some images.

Comment: @fedab what texture coordinates you are  using for mapping ?

Comment: You should post the .blend to PasteAll.org.  I used the same setup that you show in the images and it works fine for me.  It looks like something else that you are doing is affecting the results.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Okay, I added my blend file. I tried to recreate it in a new blend file... I basically only add a texture (no changes in settings like mapping, etc.), add the existing material (from the new cube when you create a new project), add curve, scale it, add modifiers. Same problem

Comment: @Chebhou The mapping settings of the texture: `Coordinates: Generated` and `Projection: Flat`. Offsets to 0, Sizes to 1, no `From Dupli`, `X, Y, Z`. This is the default setting.
Image mapping: `Extension: Repeat`, Repeat values are 1, crop minimum: 0, crop maximum: 1.
I've added a blend file too.

Comment: ah, generated coordinates.  On a side note, what's with the 2-point poly's(lines with no faces)?  They supposed to be rails?

Comment: @MarcClintDion Those "lines with no faces" at the sides are faces :) They only have a 100% transparent texture. I had the idea to use them as collision borders for a car for a game.

Comment: weird, I couldn't select them.  Transparency shouldn't affect that.

Comment: @MarcClintDion Huh, I checked the file. I can see these border things and i can select the faces in edit mode. When you switch to solid viewport shading, you should see them non-transparent. I am using Blender v2.74, maybe its because version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle this is to use UV Mapping right from the start.  For this, you can press <kbd>Numpad_7</kbd> for top view.   Now if you press <kbd>Numpad_4</kbd> several times, the view will rotate along the z-axis.  Once the positioning matches the texture orientation press <kbd>Numpad_5</kbd> to set the view to Orthographic.  Now press <kbd>u</kbd> and select "Project From View (Bounds)"
You could just use Unwrap or Reset but there is no guarantee that you will have the mapping aligned to the texture's direction.  If it's not then you'd have to rotate the UV's and/or scale by -1.0 along one of the axis(that can be confusing, it's best to avoid).

[image]

Now you should be able to apply the modifiers and have the following result.

[image]